# Using prisma db pull and prisma migrate dev

Tags: prisma

TL;DR: Is it advisable to do a `prisma migrate dev` after running `prisma db pull`?

I am working on a personal project where I using Prisma as my ORM. Most times I find myself making changes to my database schema and doing a `prisma db pull` so that the changes can reflect on my Prisma schema then edit the **models** and **model fields** names to be compliant with prisma naming conventions.

**Here is my question**: Is it good practice or advisable to run `prisma migrate dev --name edited-schema` thereafter so as to have a good migration history?

There is a time I did that and it messed with some of the constraints I had set on my database schema.

Am working with MYSQL